# Does Google Chrome support emoji on notiifcation?

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, emoji

I am making a push notification system that allows me to notify about the result of soccer match. For more detail, I made a change that adds the flags of countries on the title of the message and it worked well on mobile devices like android, but it was not the same on notification of Chrome browser. I mean that I worked but it was not what I expected.

For example, I want to show the flag of Argentina on the title, I add the code '\uD83C\uDDE6\uD83C\uDDF7' and the flag (with colors and details) of Argentina appeared, but when it shows on Chrome message, it just be the set of characters like this .

I am very confusing about this, does Google Chrome browser support to display the color emoji or not? If yes, how can I make it work both for mobile devices and browsers? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my own answer, just by adding the code Emoji Character Encoding Data by the sites like http://www.iemoji.com/ or https://www.charbase.com/block. It will work!